# Dynamically add a new dimension to array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to add a new dimension to my array aka. to my Matrix class based on user input in the constructor.

Example:

```
var matrix = new Matrix<int>(3,2,4); // is 3 dimensional array
```

Here is my `Matrix` class:

```
class Matrix<T>
{
    private T[][] mArray;
    private readonly int mCols;
    private readonly int mRows;       

    public Matrix(params int[] args)
    {
        //here is what I ve tried.
        /*
        mCols = args[0];
        mRows = args[1];

        mArray = new T[mCols][];

        for (int i = 0; i < mCols; i++)
            mArray[i] = new T[mRows];
        */

        // how to create a multidimensional array based on "args" length?

    }
}
```

Question: how to create a multidimensional array based on "args" length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it  by looking [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,156e066ecc4ccedf)

`Array.CreateInstance(typeof(YOUR_TYPE), params)`

example:

`var arr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 3, 2, 4); // creates a 3 dimensional array`